# After make connection with github repository how we can add files to repository from desktop

Tags: github

After make connection with github repository how we can add files to repository from desktop

```
      pankaj@kindlebit-desktop:~$ git remote add origin  https://github.com/SevenVerbs/ARS.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
pankaj@kindlebit-desktop:~$ git push origin master
fatal: 'e9421486fcc16bbb7d6f5630940cf333d4455c32' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
pankaj@kindlebit-desktop:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Git says there's already a remote 'origin' defined.
To remove the existing remote use the `git remote remove origin` or if it does not work `git remote rm origin`. You can then add the new remote with

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/SevenVerbs/ARS.git
```

Comment: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    --tags                import all tags and associated objects when fetching
                          or do not fetch any tag at all (--no-tags)
    -t, --track <branch>  branch(es) to track
    -m, --master <branch>
                          master branch
    --mirror[=<push|fetch>]
                          set up remote as a mirror to push to or fetch from